# Newtonsoft json - deserialize classes with same name, but different properties

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am consuming a REST API - which returns JSON. I deserialize the JSON using NewtonSOFT JSON in C#.

The returned JSON contanins an "Answer" object that contain another "Answer" object - problem is that the 2 "Answer" objects has different properties / definitions.

How can that be handled in C# or in NewtonSoft?

[Json structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njqav.png)

```
"answers": [
                {
                    "tag": {
                        "id": 803,
                        "name": "Oplysninger om bestilling af tilstandsrapporten"
                    },
                    "option": false,
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "label": "Vælg",
                            "value": "Ved hjælp af familie, venner eller bekendte mv",
                            "show_inline": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "question": "Hvordan fandt du den bygningssagkyndige?",
                    "seller_question_id": 1
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"answers" here is a property name, not a class name, so all you need to do is define your classes in a way that matches the pattern you've shown. Having two different properties named `"answers"` doesn't present any particular complication.

```
class Response
{
    public IList<OuterAnswer> answers { get; set; }
}

class OuterAnswer
{
    public Tag tag { get; set; }
    public bool option { get; set; }
    public IList<InnerAnswer> answers { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public long seller_question_id { get; set; }
}

class InnerAnswer
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public bool show_inline { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course - you're right got blind starring at the JSON and mixed up properties and classes.